# Function my_revstr

Tags: c, string, reverse

First of all, sorry for my english, i'm french.
I want to write a function, `my_revstr`. This function reverse a string but when I test it doesn't work, it launch the console and it crash.

To reverse my string I want to swap opposites char, ex :  for a string of `8 chars 0-7, 1-6, 2-5, 3-4`.
I use some function : `my_strlen (return the lenght of the string)`, `my_swap (swap the values)`, this functions works.
Here ise the code :

```
char *my_revstr(char *str)
{
int i;
int n;

i = my_strlen(str);
if (i%2 == 1) /* odd str*/
{
    i = i/2 - 1;
    n = i + 2;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        my_swap(str + i, str + n);
        i = i - 1;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
else
{
    i = i / 2 - 1;
    n = i + 1;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        my_swap(str + i, str + n);
        i = i - 1;
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the test :

```
int main()
{
my_putstr(my_revstr("Bonjour"));
return 0;
}
```

Can you help me to understand why it doesn't work ?

Comment: firstly, What does it output? and secondly are you sure that my_swap and my_strlen work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string defined using a string literal (such as `"Bonjour"`) is to be considered read-only.

Modifying such a string invokes undefined behavior.

The first step is to make it modifiable:

```
char text[] = "Bonjour";

my_putstr(my_revstr(text));
```

This creates a character array (`text`), and just uses the string literal to *initialize* the array. This means that after the first line, `text` is just an array of characters, to which you have read/write access just as with any other variable.

Also, your function is missing a `return` statement, so what pointer gets passed to `my_putstr()` is also very random. That's undefined behavior again.